# Writing a nested loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

The data:

- I have two data sets (Table 1 and Table 2) that are list of compounds detected by mass spectrometry.
- Each list of compounds contains three very basic terms - the index (i or j), retention time (RT min), and mass-to-charge ion ratio (m/z). The fourth term is the numerical ID assigned for each compound by each lab (ID_T1 or ID_T2).
- Table 1 was collected and analyzed by Lab 1. Table 1 is indexed by i.
- Table 2 was collected by Lab 1 but analyzed by Lab 2. Table 2 is
  indexed by j.

The comparison:
Two questions that I am to answer using this code are

1. "Does the m/z from Table 1[i] match the m/z from Table 2[j]?"
2. "Does the RT(min) from Table 1[i] match the RT(min) from Table 2[j]?”

The criteria:
In order to answer question 1 – MZ Matching – I would use the following criteria:

|(Table_1[i,1] – Table_2[j,1])/ Table_1[i,1])*106| < 3 ppm

In order to answer question 2 – RT Matching – I would use the following criteria:

|Table_1[i,2] – Table_2[j,2]| < 0.9

The output:
I would like each positive match (i.e. matching RT and MZ) from the for loop to be written into a new table. I don’t know if it is possible to write the match result (TRUE/FALSE) into the existing tables. I would like to be able to preserve some data from the newly combined rows (Lab ID’s from Lab 1 and Lab 2)

The progress:

```
for (i in 1:length(Table_1$RT)) 
  for (j in 1:length(Table_2$RT))
    {if abs(Table_1$RT[i]- Table_2$RT[j])<0.9 ==TRUE)
  {Table_3$RTResult<-(abs(Table_1$RT[i]- Table_2$RT[j])<0.9)
 Table_3$ID_T1 <- i
 Table_3$ID_T2 <- j}
}
  else
  {print(i)
      print(j)}}
```

Currently, most of my error messages are Error: unexpected symbol or Error: unexpected '}' so I don't know what I'm doing wrong or if I'm even on the right track!

I have attached pictures so as to visualize the problem.

[image: Output]

Comment: Please add a reproducible example as described in https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

It looks like R is upset by curly braces that don't match. But even once you fix those, there are some problems:

- You don't need to check whether `abs(Table_1$RT[i]- Table_2$RT[j]) < 0.9` is equal to `TRUE`, because that's what the `<` comparison does by itself.
- Setting `Table_3$RTResult <- ( abs(Table_1$RT[I] - Table_2$RT[j]) < 0.9 )` won't work, because there's a vector on the left and a single `TRUE`/`FALSE` value on the right of the `<-`. You would need to specify an index on the left, but I think that this line isn't doing anything useful for your result, anyway.

I think you want to pre-specify a matrix `Table_3`, where the rows match the rows of `Table_1` and the columns match the rows of `Table_2`. Then set `Table_3[i, j]` to `TRUE` if the `i`th row of `Table_1` matches the `j`th row of `Table_2`.

My code to do that would look like:

```
Table_3 = matrix( FALSE, nrow=nrow(Table_1), ncol=nrow(Table_2) )

for (i in 1:nrow(Table_1) ) {
    for (j in 1:nrow(Table_2) ) {
        Table_3[i, j] = abs(Table_1$RT[[i]] - Table_2$RT[[j]]) < 0.9 && abs( (Table_1$MZ[[i]] – Table_2$MZ[[j]]) / Table_1$MZ[[i]] * 106) < 3
    }
}
```